# disable M value and Z value by using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, environment-variable

I want to remove the M and Z values of the shapefiles, which can be done by using Feature Class to Geodatabase (multiple) and choosing Disabled for M and Z values. The following picture shows the details of the step. [image]

I want to use arcpy to realize this step so I used Copy As Python Snippet and obtained the below code.

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Input_Features="LinearRef_Travis_LS;Merged_Final", Output_Geodatabase="C:/Users/TL/Desktop/1031/New File Geodatabase.gdb")
```

The code doesn't show the part of changing the environment setting. I wonder if there is way to remove the M and Z values of shapefiles by using arcpy?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't any settings in the tool that allow you to set the environment.  However, looking at the [**documentation**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-geodatabase.htm#GUID-235790F5-C37F-41F2-9A95-567AF7080C7E) for this tool, you can see that the environments for M and Z values are honoured.

Prior to running your tool, set the appropriate environment settings as such:

```
import arcpy

# Set the outputMFlag environment to Disabled
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"

# Set the outputZFlag environment to Disabled
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"
```

Then you can run your code to convert the feature class:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Input_Features="LinearRef_Travis_LS;Merged_Final", Output_Geodatabase="C:/Users/TL/Desktop/1031/New File Geodatabase.gdb")
```

Here's the [**documentation**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-has-m-values.htm) on the "Output has M Values" flag and here's the **[documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-has-z-values.htm)** on the "Output has Z Values" flag.